# How to get path and name of the saved file in excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the following code to save the file but i am not able to get the saved file path and name .

Is there a way to get those details?

```
Sub Test3()

On Error Resume Next
Dim FileSelected As String
Dim strPath As String

FileSelected = Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show

If Not FileSelected <> "False" Then
MsgBox "You have cancelled"
Exit Sub
End If

If FileSelected <> "False" Then
strPath = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs).SelectedItems(1)
    'displays the result in a message box
Call MsgBox(strPath, vbInformation, "Save Path")
Exit Sub
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `Application.GetSaveAsFilename`.  Create a `Variant` variable, and set that to `Application.GetSaveAsFilename` after you save it.